# What happens when a clustered index on one column is dropped and a new one created on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a clustered index on one column, then I `DROP` it and create a new clustered index on another column, or create a primary key - then what physical data changes happen (actual files/pages used to store the data)?

Comment: What do you mean by physical data changes? As in what you visually see in the data from the table, or do you mean that actual files/pages used to store the data?

Comment: yes actual files/pages used to store the data

Comment: *"create a new clustered index on another column, or create a primary key"* Note that a `PRIMARY KEY` and `CLUSTERED INDEX` are not synonyms; the `PRIMARY KEY` does not need to be the `CLUSTERED INDEX`. Though often they are, there are occasions when it is not the right choice. Creating a `PRIMARY KEY` does therefore not mean you are creating a new `CLUSTERED INDEX`, and thus you may well (after `DROP`ing the `CLUSTERED INDEX`) have a table in a heap with a PK.